ActiveMQ Artemis broker.xml configuration not being applied
I'm defining the following broker.xml properties for my Artemis broker:
<address-settings>
    <!--default for catch all-->
    <address-setting match="#">
      <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
      <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
      <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>

      <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
      <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
      <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
      <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
      <!-- MY CUSTOMIZATION - BEGIN -->
      <default-purge-on-no-consumers>true</default-purge-on-no-consumers>
      <auto-delete-queues>true</auto-delete-queues>
      <auto-delete-queues-delay>300000</auto-delete-queues-delay>
      <auto-delete-addresses>true</auto-delete-addresses>
      <auto-delete-addresses-delay>300000</auto-delete-addresses-delay>
      <!-- MY CUSTOMIZATION - END -->

      <!-- The size of each page file -->
      <page-size-bytes>10M</page-size-bytes>

      <!-- When we start applying the address-full-policy, e.g paging -->
      <!-- Both are disabled by default, which means we will use the global-max-size/global-max-messages  -->
      <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
      <max-size-messages>-1</max-size-messages>

      <!-- When we read from paging into queues (memory) -->

      <max-read-page-messages>-1</max-read-page-messages>
      <max-read-page-bytes>20M</max-read-page-bytes>

      <!-- Limit on paging capacity before starting to throw errors -->

      <page-limit-bytes>-1</page-limit-bytes>
      <page-limit-messages>-1</page-limit-messages>
    </address-setting>


    <!-- MY CUSTOMIZATION - BEGIN -->
    <address-setting match="/app/control">
        <auto-create-dead-letter-resources>false</auto-create-dead-letter-resources>
    </address-setting>
    <!-- MY CUSTOMIZATION - END -->


    <!-- MY CUSTOMIZATION - BEGIN -->
    <address-setting match="notificationsTopic">
        <auto-create-dead-letter-resources>false</auto-create-dead-letter-resources>
    </address-setting>
    <!-- MY CUSTOMIZATION - END -->


    <!-- MY CUSTOMIZATION - BEGIN -->
    <address-setting match="DLQ">
        <max-size-bytes>104857600</max-size-bytes>
        <auto-delete-queues-delay>604800000</auto-delete-queues-delay>
        <default-ring-size>10000</default-ring-size>
    </address-setting>
    <!-- MY CUSTOMIZATION - END -->


    <!-- MY CUSTOMIZATION - BEGIN -->
    <address-setting match="ExpiryQueue">
        <max-size-bytes>104857600</max-size-bytes>
        <auto-delete-queues-delay>604800000</auto-delete-queues-delay>
        <default-ring-size>10000</default-ring-size>
    </address-setting>
    <!-- MY CUSTOMIZATION - END -->


    <!-- MY CUSTOMIZATION - BEGIN -->
    <address-setting match="$sys.mqtt.#">
        <default-purge-on-no-consumers>false</default-purge-on-no-consumers>
    </address-setting>
    <!-- MY CUSTOMIZATION - END -->
</address-settings>

I'm trying to check that the following customizations are being applied properly, however, when I inspect the addresses and queues properties, none of those settings are being applied.
For example, the queues created in address DLQ should have a ring size of 10000 because of parameter default-ring-size set to 10000.
The Console shows the following:

When inspecting queues matching addresses $sys.mqtt.# the same happens; default-purge-on-no-consumers is set to false and the value shown by the Console is true:

This way, I cannot find a single custom value well-reflected in the Console.
I also have inspected the logs and I don't find any trace indicating that those values are incorrect.
Why I can't se reflected the values specified un the Console? Is there a better way to test it?
UPDATE
Recently I have discovered that applying a setting directly to a queue does work. For example:
<address name="DLQ" >
   <anycast>
      <queue name="DLQ" ring-size="5" />
   </anycast>
</address>

but setting it in the address does not work at all:
<address-setting match="DLQ">
   <default-ring-size>5</default-ring-size>
</address-setting>


Did you happen to start your broker (which creates the queues) and then later change the address-settings?

Also, what version of ActiveMQ Artemis are you using?

Yes, for each change I start the broker.
Recently I noticed that if I set the values directly in the queue they are caught properly.
I'm modifying the description to bring  more context.

I'm using Artemis 2.38.0
